# for loop with an xml string

Tags: android, for-loop, android-xmlpullparser

Ok so I have an `xml string` that is passed into a function which I get from a `SOAP` request and I can't figure out what limit to set the boundary too. I have this right now but I think it filters through too many times and is wrong.

```
for(int i=0; i < xmlForTable.length(); i ++){

         TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
         TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
         row.setLayoutParams(lp);

         .......... //code

         }
```

Ideally I'd like to make it `i=0; i<xmlForTable.(count of words); i++` This way I could just loop through each word but I'm not sure on how to do this..

Any help would be nice and greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Won't you have to split xmlForTable into words first? Then you could loop through the words.

Comment: Don't see an xml string (what ever that would be) or a string with xml content. What do you mean with boundary? What should your code accomplish?